# Reload RSpec shared examples with Guard and Spork

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, spork, guard

How do I get spork to reload my shared examples when I make changes to them? I tried the following, but it's not reloading them:

```
Spork.each_run do
  Dir[Rails.root.join("spec/shared_examples/*.rb")].each {|f| require f}
end
```

I know that I can add a watcher to my Guardfile to have it reload the env when the shared examples change, but my application is big and takes about 10-15 seconds to reload the entire environment:

```
watch(/^spec\/shared_examples\/.*\.rb$/)
```

I would prefer to just have it reload the shared examples that changed though so I can have a faster feedback loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out I was *also* loading the shared_examples in Spork.prefork, and for some reason that was causing them not to reload for each run. Removing that line from Spork.prefork and only having it in Spork.each_run fixed the issue and now changes to any shared_examples are reflected any time a test runs.

Comment: How do you **not** load shared examples in the `prefork` block? We have `Dir[Rails.root.join("spec/support/**/*.rb")].each {|f| require f}` in our `prefork` block, which definitely loads everything (including shared examples). How do **you** prevent the shared examples from being loaded in the `prefork` block?

Comment: Ah, I see: we had the shared examples under `spec/support/shared_examples`, and you have it under `spec/shared_examples`. Moving them into `spec/shared_examples` works, but is this where shared examples belong to? If I don't want to move them out of the `support` folder, how can I prevent them from being loaded in the `prefork` block?

Comment: So, using this line of code in `prefork`, the shared examples are not loaded: `Dir[Rails.root.join("spec/support/**/*.rb")].reject{ |f| f[%r{/shared_examples/}] }.each { |f| require f }`.

Answer (score 8):

Here are a couple things you'll need to check:

In the environment config file `test.rb`, make sure you have this

```
  config.cache_classes = !(ENV['DRB'] == 'true')
```

That makes sure you're not caching classes if you're in the Spork environment.

Then, in the make sure these are in `.each_run`

```
FactoryGirl.reload
ActiveSupport::Dependencies.clear
ActiveRecord::Base.instantiate_observers
```

This should make sure you're reloading classes each run.

I'd also keep the your share_examples load in the `.each_run` section.

```
Spork.each_run do
  FactoryGirl.reload
  ActiveSupport::Dependencies.clear
  ActiveRecord::Base.instantiate_observers
  Dir[Rails.root.join("spec/shared_examples/*.rb")].each {|f| require f}  
end
```

You may need to play with the ordering of the 4 lines in the `.each_run` section to make sure things all load correctly.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. It turns out I was doing it right, but I was stupidly requiring the shared examples in both prefork and each_run. For some reason it was causing some sort of conflict and they were not getting loaded in each run.

Comment: Glad I could help. If you thought my answer was helpful and accurate, I'd appreciate an up-vote. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

```
Spork.prefork do
  Dir[Rails.root.join("spec/shared_examples/*.rb")].each {|f| require f}
end
```

Comment: Isn't the prefork only run once when the environment loads?

Comment: Yea, but you will be telling it to watch for those files ;)

Comment: Not sure I follow... Spork doesn't actually watch files, that's what I'm using guard for.